# default open flags for std::ostringstream

Tags: c++

Why is `std::ostringstream::ate` not part of the default open flags for ostringstream?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss.str("set some string in the stream");
  std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
  oss << "expected a concatenation, but without std::ostringstream::ate flag, the writepos is at 0 after str(\"something\")";
  std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is unexpected behavior to me, so I assume there's a reason for this default. Are there other operators (besides operator<< ) that are influenced by the open flag? Would these have unexpected behavior if the writepos would default to the end-of-string?

Comment: `str` isn't meant to be used to insert into an ostringstream; and you can set `ate` when creating `oss`if you really want to

Comment: What is str(const string& s) meant for then if not for setting a string?I know I can add ate in the constructor. I am however trying to find a reason why I would not want that flag as a default. To me the behavior without that flag is unexpected.

Comment: `str()` is mainly for use on input stringstreams, or as part of the process of resetting the output stringstream to blank. If you use the stringstream in the normal way then the difference would never arise. But I can imagine someone wanting to rewind the stream and modify the current state of the buffer.

Comment: This might all be true (I'm not convinced this violates "normal" usage), and I understand the need for istringstream, but that does has its own openflags anyway. Both classes could behave sanely, right? Basically this still doesn't answer the question I have with it: is this an accidental (erroneous/unfortunate) default or is there a reason for it.